Detect and add missing Properties in JSON Config
I want to have a class in a class library that dynamically creates a settings.json from an object T and if T is changed adds or removes the properties. I have written this class that works fine for creating the json file:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Common.Settings
{
    public static class Settings
    {
        public static string FilePath { get; private set; }
        public static string FileName { get; private set; }


        public static T UseSettings<T>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<Options>? configureOptions) where T : class, new()
        {
            var options = new Options();
            configureOptions?.Invoke(options);

            FilePath = options.Path;
            FileName = options.FileName;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(options.Path, options.FileName);

            // Check if the JSON file exists
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
                Directory.CreateDirectory(options.Path);

                // Create a new instance of type T with initialized nested properties
                var settings = CreateDefaultSettings<T>();

                // Serialize the default settings
                var defaultSettings = JsonSerializer.Serialize(settings);

                // Write the default settings to the JSON file
                File.WriteAllText(filePath, defaultSettings);
            }

            // Read the JSON file
            var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            // Deserialize the JSON into a JObject
            var rootElement = JsonDocument.Parse(json).RootElement;

            // Get properties of type T
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            // Flag to indicate if any property mismatch found
            var mismatchFound = false;

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                // Check if property exists in the JSON object
                if (!rootElement.TryGetProperty(property.Name, out var propertyElement))
                {
                    mismatchFound = true;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Property '{property.Name}' not found in {options.FileName}");
                    rootElement = UpdateJsonObject<T>(rootElement, filePath);
                    continue; // Skip to next property
                }

            }

            if (mismatchFound)
            {
                // Handle property mismatch (e.g., update JSON, log a warning)
                //Console.WriteLine($"** Property mismatches found in {options.FileName} JSON configuration. Consider updating the {options.FileName} file or handling the mismatches in your application. **");
                Console.WriteLine($"** Property mismatches found in {options.FileName} JSON configuration. The missing properties were added to {options.FileName}. **");
            }

            // Deserialize the JSON into an instance of type T
            var deserializedSettings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);

            // Register an instance of the Settings class with the deserialized values
            services.AddSingleton(deserializedSettings);
            return deserializedSettings;
        }

        private static T CreateDefaultSettings<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            var settings = new T();
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                {
                    var nestedSettings = typeof(Settings).GetMethod("CreateDefaultSettings", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                        .MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType)
                        .Invoke(null, null);

                    property.SetValue(settings, nestedSettings);
                }
            }

            return settings;
        }

        private static JsonElement UpdateJsonObject<T>(JsonElement element, string filePath) where T : class, new()
        {
            var settings = new T();
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(property);
                if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                {
                    var nestedSettings = typeof(Settings).GetMethod("UpdateJsonObject", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                        .MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType)
                        .Invoke(null, [element, filePath]);

                    if (element.TryGetProperty(property.Name, out var ele))
                    {
                        property.SetValue(settings, ele);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        property.SetValue(settings, nestedSettings);
                    }

                }
            }
            var defaultSettings = JsonSerializer.Serialize(settings);

            // Write the default settings to the JSON file
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, defaultSettings);
            return JsonDocument.Parse(defaultSettings).RootElement;
        }

    }



    public class Options
    {
        public string Path { get; set; } = "config";
        public string FileName { get; set; } = "settings.json";

    }
}

When changing T I run into the following error that I can't quite get my head through:
System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' cannot be converted to type 'Common.Settings.JWTSecuritySettings'.'
The error concerns a nested class in T as seen here:
  public class AppSettings{
    public string Servicename { get; set; }
    public string AppDomain { get; set; }

    public JWTSecuritySettings JWTSettings { get; set; }

    public DBConnectionSettings DBSettings { get; set; }

    public string TenantDBEncryptionKey { get; set; }
  }

  public class JWTSecuritySettings
  {
    public string PrivateKey { get; set; }
    public string PublicKey { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; } = "http://localhost:5001";
  }

  public class DBConnectionSettings
  {
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } 
                              ="Host=localhost;Database=DEVDB;Username=postgres;Password=post";
    public string DBName { get; set; }
  }

I tried removing the if statement and only use the else section but that did nothing, just gave me another error

It's really strange, because by using your code I don't get the same error. It actually seems to work. Try delete the file and restart again by making your utility regenerate your file for the first time (again).

@claudiom248 It works when creating the file but not when adding a property to the model and executing it. I tried it from several points in my app, that's what startles me, especially when you're saying that it works on your end

Sorry for my misreading. I have put the answer that should fix your problem.

Sorry for my misreading,
I achieved to resolve the problem.
Simply put, you where trying to assign a JsonElement to a property of a type not compatible with that kind of object.

if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
{
    var nestedSettings = (JsonElement)typeof(Settings).GetMethod("UpdateJsonObject", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        .MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType)
        .Invoke(null, [element, filePath]);

    if (element.TryGetProperty(property.Name, out var ele))
    {
        property.SetValue(settings, ele);
    }
    else
    {
        property.SetValue(settings, nestedSettings.Deserialize(property.PropertyType));
    }

}

First of all, you have to convert the return type of the Invoke method to a JsonElement. The JsonElement class expose the Deserialize object that you can use to cast the element to your actual model.
